# Check if elements of one list are in elements of other sub-list

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, substring

I am using **Faker** library.

```
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()
```

I have a list of sub-lists (2 elements each); a column name to give the dataframe, and the function invocation itself.

---

A list of all function names, excluding names of functions that start with a "_":

```
my_list = [[m, 'fake.'+m+'()'] for m in dir(fake) if m[0] != '_']
my_list
>>> [['add_provider', 'fake.add_provider()'],
 ['address', 'fake.address()'], ...
```

Now, I want to add another condition to the same for loop, excluding function names.

Attempted Solution:

```
exclude = ['add_provider']
fake_cols = [[m, 'fake.'+m+'()'] for m in dir(fake) if function_name in exclude or function_name[:1] == "_"]
fake_cols
```

Output is empty:

```
[]
```

Any solutions that are more concise would be appreciated.

Comment: Just get rid of the any? Does that work?

Comment: It still includes the "add_provider" method name in my "exclude" list. Latest code and output above

Comment: There is also something odd with ```[m, 'fake.'+m+'()'``` m is a list is it?

Comment: m is the name of a method

Comment: so my_list is exacly build as dir(fake) ?

Comment: No, a subset of it `my_list = [[m, 'fake.'+m+'()'] for m in dir(fake) if m[0] != '_']` where we exclude certain functions that begin with `_`

Comment: Can you look at my answer and tell me, if thats what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a little overhaul would do it, look at the following, if that does what you are aiming for:

```
import faker

faker = faker.Faker()

exclude = ["add_provider", "address"]
faker_functions ={}
for function_name in dir(faker):
    if function_name in exclude or function_name[:1] == "_":
        continue
    try:
        faker_functions[function_name] =  getattr(faker, function_name)
    except:
        continue

def get_list_of_fake_functions():
    return list(faker_funcktions.keys())

def get_fake(fake_function):
    return faker_functions[fake_function]()

my_list =  [[key, "faker."+ key+ "()"] for key in faker_functions.keys()]
my_list
```

Error as expected because excluded:

```
get_fake("zipcode_plus4")
KeyError: 'zipcode_plus4'
```

or result if not

```
get_fake("zipcode_plus4")
Out[38]: '71875-8723'
```

my_list

```
my_list[:10]
Out[57]: 
[['administrative_unit', 'faker.administrative_unit()'],
 ['am_pm', 'faker.am_pm()'], ...
```

Comment: This yields me an empty `dict` `{}`. I don't think a `try-catch` is necessary. I think my problem is with my `for loop`'s `if condition`. I ensured my `Faker` instance was named the same as yours.

Comment: This cant yield an empty dictionary, I get a full dict of all functions with the above code

Comment: Can you execute just my snipped and see, if you can execute ```get_fake("zipcode_plus4")```?

Comment: Getting an output now. However, this is too far from what I require. My layout as explained in the post is what I need. I imagine it's something to do with my if condition.

Comment: Could you try altering my attempted solution at the bottom of my post, please?

Comment: I added a ```my_list``` variable, is that what you need?

Comment: It works! I have a slight update to your solution